# Metropolis-Hastings for doubly-unnormalised densities?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, monte-carlo, simulation

I wish to do inference in a joint space $P(x,y)$ that is particularly tricky, because I don't have access to an unnormalised density $f(x,y)\propto P(x,y)$. However, I do have:

An unnormalised marginal density for $x$
$$f(x) \propto P(x)$$

and an unnormalised conditional density for $y$
$$g(y;x) \propto P(y|x)$$

Is there any way for me to set up Metropolis Hastings in this space, so that the Markov chain converges in distribution to $P(x,y)$?